# VB6 redim error "This array is fixed or temporarily locked"

Tags: vb6, dynamic-arrays

I have a global array variable g () which starts with 3 object values.
I then call a sub that uses as input one of the items in g, and that needs to create additional items in g, plus update the item provided.

Something along the lines of

Declaration:

> Public g() As branch

Initialization:

> ReDim g (1 To 3)
>       Set g(1) = br1
>       Set g(2) = br2
>       Set g(3) = br3

Code call of sub

> Call chg (g(2))

Sub

> Public Sub chg (ByRef br As branch)
>       r = UBound(g)
>       ReDim g (1 To r + 2)
>       ... (rest of the code)
>   End Sub

The code errors on the Redim statement, with error text "This array is fixed or temporarily locked".

Why can't I change the size of the array in this sub? What to do different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the MSDN documentation:

> You tried to redimension a module-level dynamic array, in which one
>   element has been passed as an argument to a procedure. For example, in
>   the following code, ModArray is a dynamic, module-level array whose
>   forty-fifth element is being passed by reference to the Test procedure.
>
> There is no need to pass an element of the module-level array in this
>   case, since it's visible within all procedures in the module. However,
>   if an element is passed, the array is locked to prevent a deallocation
>   of memory for the reference parameter within the procedure, causing
>   unpredictable behavior when the procedure returns.

```
Dim ModArray() As Integer    ' Create a module-level dynamic array.

Sub AliasError()
   ReDim ModArray(1 To 73) As Integer
   Test ModArray(45)    ' Pass an element of the module-level array to the Test procedure.
End Sub

Sub Test(SomeInt As Integer)
   ReDim ModArray (1 To 40) As Integer  ' Error occurs here.
End Sub
```

One idea would be to pass the index of the array instead of the object itself.

Comment: Thanks - I will pass the index only to the sub.

Comment: It's been a long time since I worked with VB6, but isn't Redim Preserve required to keep reference to the existing elements on the Redim?